# Windows explorer takes at least 1 minute to show shortcuts each time I open it

Tags: windows, performance, windows-explorer

At some point a few weeks ago, when I'm opening a new explorer or even a new tab, explorer takes ages to become fully operational. In the meantime it looks like this:

[image]

I can type a path, browse, etc.. but my shortcuts (on the left) aren't available for at least one minute. After that, they appear. But if I open another tab, here it goes again.

Also, all file explorers don't show the shortcuts ever, only the drives.

Of course, killing explorer, rebooting, does nothing. It's a permanent thing.

[image]

I've googled for this error but never really could find the exact error I have. Most people get permanent slowdowns, that's not my case: file navigation is fast enough.

note that I have only a SSD drive, no mechanical slow HDD or such.

Comment: Do you have any network drives there that are showing as disconnected drives?

Comment: Network drives can be problematic by being slow to respond.

Comment: Are there any errors in Reliability History relating to Windows Explorer?

Comment: Try temporarily uninstalling your cloud data storage providers that may occur in that list (e.g. Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive etc) or maybe https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html

Comment: yes, it seems to be a problem with Ubuntu drive you are right

Answer (score 0):

Comments made me realize that there were issues with some networked drives.

I don't really have networked drives so I didn't think it was the issue but I *do* have Ubuntu installed, and the Linux drive didn't open properly.

It used to work, but a driver configuration changed somehow with a windows update probably. So I updated the registry as indicated here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/7742

Changing the order in

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order

to put P9NP first, reboot...

and ubuntu started. And no more delays when opening explorer.